# How to create a replicaset through a custom resource?

Tags: kubernetes

I want to create a custom resource that is able to create a replicaset under a certain event. What is the best way to accomplish this?

Note that I am aware of deployment, but deployment does not meet my intended use cases.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you might be looking into building something that would suit more or less the operator pattern.

- https://coreos.com/operators/
- https://coreos.com/blog/introducing-operators.html
- https://github.com/coreos/prometheus-operator

Generaly you need to watch on some resources including your custom ones with kube client and act based on events propagated from kube API.